# Tangent to circle in 3D

Tags: geometry

A question in my analytical geometry book asked me to find a tangent line to a 3D circle which made me think about this.
Can there be a meaning of  "tangent line" in case the circle is in 3D or even a "tangent plane" ? Because if I consider definition of tangent to a point for a curve that it should only "touch" the curve at that point, then for a 3D circle, shouldn't it be "family of planes"?

Comment: No. There is no difference. The tangent to a circle means the same thing. Think of a particle moving along the circle. If you froze time then the tangent line would lie along the direction of travel of the particle. That line will be in the same plane as the circle, regardless of where the circle lives.

Comment: This is convincing but I am unable to find a source which says that "tangent should always lie in same plane".

Comment: I cannot even imagine a line that isn't incident to a plane in Euclidean space where the dimension is greater than $1$.

Comment: I think there's a confusion here. I said "same plane" not "some plane".

Comment: I see. The missing article confused me. In this case, it does because the curve is lying in a plane even if it is not one described as simply as the $xy$ plane. If you move along this curve, you will never travel in a direction that leaves the plane of the circle.

Comment: If the curve is planar, then all of its tangents will lie on that plane, too, but there’s no requirement that it be in “the same plane,” as that’s not a well-defined concept for a general spatial curve, such as a helix.

Answer (score 2):

The tangent at that point signifies the direction of the curve at that point and hence has to be in the same plane.

Comment: Try to elaborate the answer so that every user can easily understand this fact

Answer (score 0):

I would try to answer the question assuming it's for a sphere in 3D.

A sphere in 3D would be written as $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-a)^2-r^2=0$ or simply the surface $f(x)=0\ where\ f(x):=(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-a)^2-r^2$. One would intuitively define the tangent to its surface at a point P by a set of lines which are tangent at P to a curve(lying in the surface) passing through P(note: line tangent to one curve might not be tangent to another curve).

Now let's write the curve as X(t) i.e. (as a parametric curve) and clearly it should satisfy $f(X(t))=0$, differentiating the given expression with respect to t by applying the chain rule, you would get $$\nabla f(X(t)).\frac{dX}{dt}(t)=0$$ suppose that the point where we wanted to find the tangent is at $t_0$,i.e., point= $X(t_0)$=P, so the above equation would give 
$$\nabla f(X(t_0)).\frac{dX}{dt}(t_0)=0$$
which would mean that $\nabla f(X(t_0))$ is perpendicular to tangent of every curve along the surface at the point P(since X(t) was any arbitrary curve). This naturally leads us to suspect that all the tangents would then have to lie in a plane since they are are all perpendicular to the vector $\nabla f(X(t_0))$. To confirm that this is indeed a plane you can verify that for 2 orthogonal circles(tangent at the point of intersection are perpendicular) passing point P would give perpendicular tangents and hence their direction vectors would be linearly independent and would span this plane.

Comment: So you are saying that in 3D , it has to be a "tangent plane" and not "tangent lines" for a circle or more generally , for any curve?

Comment: No, I'm saying that for a surface, its a plane but for a curve, its a line. I've shown how the generalization comes about naturally for a surface in 3D(in your case, the surface of a sphere). So, if you would talk purely of a circle in 3D the tangent is still a line but for its generalization in 3D,  a sphere its a plane.

Comment: Don't be confused, a sphere is a 3D($r, \theta, \phi$)  object with a surface which is 2D($\theta, \phi$, since r is fixed) but a circle is 1D(only one parameter$(t)$ eg $r(cost,sint)$, here $r$ is fixed). Simply put dimension= the minimum number of variables required to describe your object.